# Magento re-index issue with different computers

Tags: php, sql, database, magento, mage

I have been stuck on this bizarre issue lately with re-indexing the Catalog Search Index.

I have created a custom module that has an event observer that looks for the re-index process complete event and then runs some additional operations on the catalogsearch_index table in the database.

When I run the index, everything works as planned.  When certain other computers run the index process it simply ignores my extension as if the event is not called.  Some other computers work and some do not.  I have enabled the

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

error line in the index.php file to see errors and there are none on my machine or theirs.

What could possibly be causing this?  All of the code is PHP and thus should be run server side.  Why would the different computers change how my code follows the indexing process?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:  I have just found out that my code is not being executed at all on other machines.  So apparently on the other machines my event observer is not observing and running my script.  Why would this be?  Thanks.

Comment: Try also set error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Have you cleared your Magento cache on each server that it's running on?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is to check the log files and see, if you can find anything there. You can also log your actions in your observer to find out whats going on.

Are you sure, that the problem is related to particular computers? 
It could be related to the php execution time: possibly, during certain times, the server is under such a load, that the reindex process actually never finishes and therefore, your observer code might not be executed.

I always do the reindexing using ssh:

```
cd /your/magento/directory
php shell/indexer.php reindexall
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check for to make sure your module is even being installed on the other systems. Check for the correct line in core_resource.